# How to structure SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table that contains a list of tasks;

TableName: Tasks.  Fields: (ID Int, Description nvarchar)

The tasks are completed daily and are logged in a table like follows;

TableName TasksDone. Fields: (TaskID Int, TaskDate DateTime)

I need to have a query that runs for a date range and shows the tasks that were NOT done (do not exist in the TasksDone table) for every date in the range.

I hope that makes sense...
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's no built in functionality in SQL Server to get all dates in a range, or similar. You need to build it using a numbers table or a calendar table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a numbers or calendar table to make things easy, or we can simulate one if the range is small. Is the TaskDate a plain date, or does it have a time component also?

Basic plan of attack is:

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime

/* Set @StartDate and @EndDate to represent the range */

with Digits as (
    select 0 as d union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
    select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
), Numbers as (
    select (D1.d * 100) + (D2.d * 10) + D3.d as n
    from Digits D1,Digits D2,Digits D3
), TaskDates as (
    select
        t.TaskID,
        DATEADD(day,n.n,@StartDate) as TaskDate
    from
        Tasks t
            inner join
        Numbers n
            on
                DATEADD(day,n.n,@StartDate) <= @EndDate
)
select
    *
from
    TaskDates td1
        left join
    TasksDone td2
        on
            td1.TaskID = td2.TaskID and
            DATEDIFF(day,td1.TaskDate,td2.TaskDate) = 0
where
    td2.TaskID is null
```

The first two CTEs build a small numbers table, the 3rd CTE constructs a set of TaskIDs and Dates within the required range. The final select matches theses against the TasksDone table, and then discards those rows where a match is found. If TasksDone.TaskDate is a plain date (no time component) and @StartDate is also with no time component, then you can ditch the DATEDIFF and just use td1.TaskDate = td2.TaskDate.

If you need a large range (above can cover ~3 years), I'd suggest building a proper number table or calendar table

Comment: Awesome, this looks great! Give me a few minutes to try it!

Comment: @rickj - make sure you use the current version - I had the arguments to DATEADD the wrong way around when I first posted it.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Works a treat. Thanks also for the great explanation, helps me understand exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straight forward, if I'm understanding the problem correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tasks
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TaskID FROM TasksDone WHERE TaskDate BETWEEN x AND y)
```

Replace `x` and `y` with the date you're after.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for that. The catch is I need to show the missing tasks for every date in the range, all tasks must be done every day. I need to show the tasks missing for every day in the range. Make sense?

Comment: @Lieven, yes I did, and no it doesn't give me what I am after. It only shows tasks not done in the entire range, not for every date in the range. All tasks in the Tasks table need to be completed EVERY day. I need to show all tasks that were missing for EVERY day in the range.

Comment: @rickj: <slap forehead> I misunderstood. </slap forehead>

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this out but see if this helps:

```
select ID, TaskDate as A from Tasks,TasksDone
where TaskID not in (select TaskID from TasksDone where TaskDate = A)
GROUP BY TaskDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, following statement should get you the tasks that didn't get executed every day in the entire range.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    @Tasks t
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  TaskID
          FROM    @TasksDone td
          WHERE   td.TaskDate BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd        
          GROUP BY
                  td.TaskID
          HAVING  COUNT(TaskID) < CAST(@RangeEnd - @RangeStart AS INTEGER)+1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT  TaskID
          FROM    @TasksDone td
          WHERE   TaskID NOT IN (SELECT TaskID 
                                 FROM   @TasksDone 
                                 WHERE  TaskDate BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd)
        ) td ON td.TaskID = t.ID
```

---

**Test script**

```
DECLARE @Tasks TABLE (
  ID INTEGER
  , DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR(32)
)

DECLARE @TasksDone TABLE (
  TaskID INTEGER
  , TaskDate DATETIME
)

DECLARE @RangeStart DATETIME
DECLARE @RangeEnd DATETIME

SET @RangeStart = GetDate() - 1
SET @RangeEnd = GetDate() + 1

INSERT INTO @Tasks
          SELECT 1, 'Done Every Day in range.'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Done a few times in range.'
UNION ALL SELECT 3 , 'Not done anytime in range.'

INSERT INTO @TasksDone
          SELECT 1, @RangeStart
UNION ALL SELECT 1, GetDate()
UNION ALL SELECT 1, @RangeEnd
UNION ALL SELECT 2, GetDate()
UNION ALL SELECT 3, GetDate() + 2

SELECT  t.*
FROM    @Tasks t
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  TaskID
          FROM    @TasksDone td
          WHERE   td.TaskDate BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd        
          GROUP BY
                  td.TaskID
          HAVING  COUNT(TaskID) < CAST(@RangeEnd - @RangeStart AS INTEGER)+1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT  TaskID
          FROM    @TasksDone td
          WHERE   TaskID NOT IN (SELECT TaskID FROM @TasksDone WHERE TaskDate BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd)
        ) td ON td.TaskID = t.ID
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven, just noticed your answer. I will give it a try as well!

Comment: No problem. A bit lit to the party it seems but if you could, let us know the results.

Comment: @rickj, I've messed up the `HAVING` clause. The answer has been edited to fix the error.

Comment: just tested, but it doesnt give me what I am after, if you look at the other answer, it gives the dates, and taskid for all tasks not done on every day in the range. For example, for your "Not done anytime in range." I should get a result for every day that this is not done, not just once for the range. Many thanks anyway for your time and effort.

Comment: @rickj, I misunderstood (again). Thank you for letting us know.